# Height Percentage becomes height of image instead of screen

Tags: html

I'm using Chrome, and i'm trying to make a selection menu.

(please don't judge me for using tables I don't want to learn CSS)

http://jsfiddle.net/scottbeebiwan/FZB7C/44/

```
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0">

  <tr>

    <td colspan="2">
      <center>
        <a href="signup.htm">Sign up<br /><img src="http://placehold.it/243x267" height="50%"></a>
      </center>
    </td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>
      <center>
        <a href="download.htm">Download<br /><img src="http://placehold.it/243x267" width="50%"></a>
      </center>
    </td>

    <td>
      <center>
        <a href="upload.php">Upload<br /><img src="http://placehold.it/243x267" width="50%"></a>
      </center>
    </td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

If you zoom out (or change the window resolution), The `Sign Up` image gets smaller while the rest of the images stay about the same size.

Answer (score 1):

For sign up element, you are setting the height to 50%, while for the other two, you are setting the width. You might want to set the height of all the 3 elements.

Comment: that doesn't seem to be the case. Have you tried saving the HTML in an html file and open in a browser?

Comment: Nope. Just makes the bottom half stretch.